# Char to Char* Error Message

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Everytime I try to compile my program, I get the Char to Char* compile error... I am doing this in C. This is my code:

```
int my_strcmp(char s1[], char s2[]) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i != '\0'; i++)
    if (my_strcmp(s1[i], s2[i]) == 1)
      return 1;
    else if (my_strcmp(s1[i], s2[i]) == -1)
      return -1;
    else
      return 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please show COMPLETE code and the specific errors, etc.

Comment: Why are you calling `my_strcmp` recursively *and* iteratively?  In any case, the signature takes a `char[]` but you pass it a `char` in the recursive call.  I also doubt you want to check whether `i == '\0'` as a loop termination condition.

Comment: After changing the code *and* the question: The compiler is correct., you are using a variable named `s` but it has never been declared.

Comment: Rather than modifying your question to a (relatively) new question, please post a new question. If the answers so far are confusing, then please post a comment on them asking for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

- `s1` has type `char *`
- Therefore, `s1[i]` has type `char`
- `my_strcmp()` expects two `char *` variables as arguments.
- You pass `s1[i]` (which we just said is a `char`) as one of the arguments.
- `char` and `char *` are different types.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `my_strcmp` is declared to use array of chars as input arguments (`char*` or equivalently `char[]`), whereas in line `if (my_strcmp(s1[i], s2[i]) == 1)` this function is invoked with characters `s1[i]` and `s2[i]`. Hence the compiler complains about `char` to `char*` conversion.