# compare 2 string recursive in c

Tags: c, string, algorithm, recursion

I write a function that gets 2 string and compare it recursive, there some rules: if there double letter or small instead of capital/opposite it is return `1`, else `0`. It supposed to return `1` if `s1` is capital letter or small and the `s` is the opposite but don't know how, I tried `*s-32/*s+32` but I cannot be sure which or when to use.

this is the function code:

```
int CompareS(char *s, char *s1)
{

if (*s == NULL && *s1==NULL)
    return 1;

if (strncmp(s, s1, 1) != 0 )
{
    if (strncmp(s, s - 1, 1) == 0)
        return CompareS(s + 1, s1);
    else
        return 0;
}
else 
    return CompareS(s + 1, s1 + 1);
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: This looks wrong... `strncmp(s, s - 1, 1)`, I only see `s` and no `s1`

Comment: [`int tolower(int ch);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower)

Comment: remember `char c = *s;` or  `char c = s[0]` will give the first character of the string.

Comment: strncmp(s,s-1,s) means that if s1=good and s=gooooood it is ok

Comment: I will give an example: s1=Happy Winter s=happpy Wiintter. The function should return 1 because it doesnt matter if there is double letter or if in s it is 'h' and in the s1 it is 'H'.

Comment: Function have ti compare two strings without care about the double letters and without care if the letters capital or not ..hope it helped.

Comment: Eerily similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098683/s-not-declared-in-scope-error-message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really liked the problem so I decided to give a **try**. Here is the code with comments. So I proceeded like that

`return 0`  : the two strings are equal

`return -1` : the two strings are **NOT** equal

`return -2` : one or both of pointers is a `NULL` pointer

```
#include <string.h> //to use the strcmp() function
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> // tolower() function in order to ignore the
                   // lower and upper cases

int CompareS(char *s, char *s1)
{
   // if one of the pointer is a NULL pointer return directly -2
   // in order to stop the process
    if(s==NULL || s1==NULL)
        return -2;
    // if the function strcmp return 0 this means that the rest of
    // the two strings are identical
    if(strcmp(s,s1)==0)
        return 0;

    // we need to see the next character to know which pointer  
    // will be incremented in the next recursive call
    if(tolower(s[0])==tolower(s1[0]) && tolower(s[0])==tolower((s1+1)[0]))
        CompareS(s, ++s1);
    else if(tolower(s[0])==tolower(s1[0]) && tolower(s1[0])==tolower((s+1)[0]))
        CompareS(++s, s1);
    else if(tolower(s[0])==tolower(s1[0]))
        CompareS(++s, ++s1);
    else
        return -1;
}
```

a Tiny test for this program for strings `hello` and `HeLLlloOOO`

```
int main()
{
    char str[100]="hello",s[100]="HeLLlloOOO";
    printf("the result of comparison is %d\n",CompareS(s, str));

    return 0;
}
```

gives

```
the result of comparison is 0
```

Hope it helps !